# Django Rest Framework inner function is not getting called in custom decorator

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, decorator

I have added my decorator(**is_same_domain_authorized_user**) in urls.py. When I call the /login-user/ url. It is not calling my decorator (**is_same_domain_authorized_user**). Can anyone spot my mistake????

Note: I should call the decorator from urls.py itself.(this is my scenario)

**decorators.py**

```
def is_same_domain_authorized_user(view_func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return is_same_domain_authorized_user
    return wrapper
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login-user/', is_same_domain_authorized_user(views.TokenView.as_view()))
]
```

Thanks

Comment: has test,it's work fine

Comment: For me it is not at all calling my inner function (wrapper) in decorator. At the same time its returning a Error called : Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /login-user/

Comment: TokenView must ask for auth perm in your code,change it change try again

Comment: Anyhow inner function should be called right... It is not getting called.

Comment: it's not get called because the framework stop it by `TokenView.as_view() `step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_same_domain_authorized_user(view_func):
    **@wraps(view_func)**
    def check_domain_permission(request):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return view_func(request)
    return check_domain_permission
```

by adding @wraps(view_func) its working fine...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

add this on top :

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

add this on the top of your function.like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def is_same_domain_authorized_user(view_func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return is_same_domain_authorized_user
    return wrapper
```